# How can assign multiple categories to product programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, programmatically

I Have a multiple categories for products . I want to assign these categories to specific products programtically .
Here is my code to run now.

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('name', $cat)->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
->addAttributeToSelect('id');
foreach($categories as $cget){
    $cat_ids = $cget['entity_id'];
//  echo $checksku; echo "<br/>"; die();
$prodLoad = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$prodID = $prodLoad->getIdBySku($pid);
if ($prodID != '' || $prodID != null ){     
    $prodLoad->load($prodID);
    $cat_ids= array();
    $cat_ids = $prodLoad->getCategoryIds();
    $cat_ids[] = $cat_id;
    $prodLoad->setCategoryIds($cat_ids);
    $prodLoad->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is killing it: `$cat_ids = $cget['entity_id'];` as you're then resetting it to a blank array later on.  Also, you can probably load your product slightly quicker too.  Try this (not tested).

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('name', $cat)
->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
->addAttributeToSelect('id');

foreach($categories as $cget) {
$cat_id = $cget->getId();
$prodLoad = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product' )->loadByAttribute("sku", array("eq" => $pid));
if ( $prodLoad->getId() != '') {
    $cat_ids   = array();
    $cat_ids   = $prodLoad->getCategoryIds();
    if (!in_array($cat_id, $cat_ids)) {
        $cat_ids[] = $cat_id;
        $prodLoad->setCategoryIds( $cat_ids );
        $prodLoad->save();
    }
}
}
```